# Does PA prove a sentence asserting that all of I-sigma(n) theories are consistent?

Tags: lo.logic

We know that PA proves consistency of $I\Sigma_{n}$ for any $n$. But does PA prove the sentence:
$\forall  n (con(I\Sigma_{n}))$?

Comment: I'm quite certain that sentence in question implies consistency of PA.

Comment: I might be missing something, but isn't it clear that that's in fact equivalent to the consistency of PA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Given any $\varphi\in \mathcal{L}_{PA}$, if $PA\vdash \varphi$ then there exists $n$ such that $I\Sigma_n\vdash \varphi$ (by finitarity of proofs). So $\forall n con(I\Sigma_n)$ implies for any $n$ $I\Sigma_n \not \vdash 0=1$ therefore $PA\not \vdash 0=1$, i.e. $con(PA).$

Comment: Dear Zhang, it is not obvious that your argument can be formulated **inside** PA or not; we know (in metalanguage) that  if PA⊢φ then there exists n such that IΣn⊢φ, but dose PA proves arithmetized version of this fact ?

Comment: Suppose you could formalize $\forall n I\Sigma_n^0$ in PA in the first place, then for any model of PA, $\{n: I\Sigma_n^0\vdash \varphi\}$ is an arithmetic set in the model. Take the least element and it would be a real natural number.

Comment: @PayamSeraji Yes, it is obvious that PA proves "for all $\phi$, if PA proves $\phi$ then so does $I\Sigma_n$ for some $n$." Proof formalizable in PA: Assume PA proves $\phi$ and let $n$ be the Gödel number of a proof $p$ of $\phi$ in PA. Then $n$ (vastly) exceeds the number of quantifiers in $p$. So $p$ is also a proof of $\phi$ in $I\Sigma_n$.